# How can I use an img id="image1" from another piece of javascript to pop up on click?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to make it so that when a user on the website clicks on a thumbnail it will pop up in an overlay as full size. I have found a ton of different ways to do this when you can specify the actual image source, however I need to specify an image source out of another piece of javascript.

I am currently using this code to pull the product description, price, and picture URL out of a google sheet:

```
<!--Begin Javascript to pull Product/Price/Picture_URL Info from google sheet-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // https://google,developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#gid
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    // Add your sheets url and range below
    var spreadsheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l6FmSuwU2E134UuxoNyRfvTw2UY_0G0q69ZwfbQy3mY/edit?range=B12:D20";
    var query = new google.visualization.Query(spreadsheetUrl);
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
  }

  function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    var dataTable = response.getDataTable();
    // getValue(rowIndex, columnIndex)
    document.getElementById("product1").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(0, 0);

    document.getElementById("price1").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(0, 1);

    document.getElementById("image1").src = dataTable.getValue(0, 2);

  }

 </script>
```

Then I show the product thumbnails with description and price using this:

```
    <!--Begin Product Description/Price/Image Blocks--> 

     <div id="description1" style="position: absolute; width: 170px; height: 18px; z-index: 64; left: 390px; top: 547px">
<p id="product1" align="center"></p>
</div>
     <div id="money1" style="position: absolute; width: 170px; height: 18px; z-index: 63; left: 390px; top: 570px">
<p id="price1" align="center"></p>
</div>
    <div id="picture1" style="position: absolute; width: 160px; height: 190px; z-index: 5; left: 395px; top: 355px; right: 645px;">
<img id="image1" src="" width="162" height="192" align="center"><img>
    </div>
```

I'm not sure how to use the `img id="image1"` as the source to pop the image up larger over the top of my page.

TIA!

Comment: You want to open the same image from `id="image1"` in a pop up?

Comment: Yes. As it is right now these are just medium sized thumbnails. I'd like to open the full size image, preferably in something similar to lightbox. I just don't know how to use that `image1` as the source as everything that I've seen either wants a local path or a url.

Comment: So where is the full size image url?

Comment: The full size image url is pulled out of a google spreadsheet in the first javascript block in this line `document.getElementById("image1").src = dataTable.getValue(0, 2);` .

Comment: So just take the source from `#image1` and put it in the source of another image which is in the lightbox or full size. Do u need js for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt.

Is fancybox okay?

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/BGogurt/pen/KVoXGE)

```html
<!--Begin Javascript to pull Product/Price/Picture_URL Info from google sheet-->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();
  })

  // https://google,developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#gid
  google.load('visualization', '1', {
    packages: ['corechart', 'line']
  });
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    // Add your sheets url and range below
    var spreadsheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l6FmSuwU2E134UuxoNyRfvTw2UY_0G0q69ZwfbQy3mY/edit?range=B12:D20";
    var query = new google.visualization.Query(spreadsheetUrl);
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
  }

  function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    var dataTable = response.getDataTable();
    // getValue(rowIndex, columnIndex)
    document.getElementById("product1").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(0, 0);

    document.getElementById("price1").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(0, 1);

    document.getElementById("image1").src = dataTable.getValue(0, 2);

    document.getElementById("img1").href = dataTable.getValue(0, 2);
  }
</script>

<!--Begin Product Description/Price/Image Blocks-->

<div id="description1" style="position: absolute; width: 170px; height: 18px; z-index: 64; left: 390px; top: 547px">
  <p id="product1" align="center"></p>
</div>
<div id="money1" style="position: absolute; width: 170px; height: 18px; z-index: 63; left: 390px; top: 570px">
  <p id="price1" align="center"></p>
</div>

<div id="picture1" style="position: absolute; width: 160px; height: 190px; z-index: 5; left: 395px; top: 355px; right: 645px;" data-role>

  <a id="img1" class="fancybox" rel="group" href="">
    <img id="image1" src="" width="162" height="192" align="center">
    <img>
  </a>

</div>
```